# Message not delivered with Orange SMS API

Tags: orange-api

I am using PHP library on github "github.com/ismaeltoe/osms-php" to access Orange SMS API . no sms is delivered to any number in the same country.

This is the message i get after sending a message.[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rH2wl.jpg)

This is the message i get when i check my sms balance [Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ayWg4.jpg)

The sms balance was 100 and it is now 88 as shown in the image but nothing was recieved.

Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because only the vendor's support can address the issue.

Comment: refer to this link https://developer.orange.com/support

Comment: In Ask the community section "The Orange API team is active on Stack Overflow with the tag orange-api, making it a useful resource if you have any questions.

Comment: They can say that all they like, but [Why we're not customer support for your favorite company](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company) still applies.

Comment: if u dont know the issue, may be others who worked with this API faced the same problem so they can help!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so, I was able to send SMS with Orange SMS API.
Firstly, You can not send SMS to phone number outside of the country's API you are using.
I've written a post about [how to send SMS using Orange SMS API](https://informagenie.com/3141/envoyer-sms-orange-sms-api/) with more explications but in french.